# Explain replication-offset-checkpoint AND recovery-point-offset in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Can Some explain what these files means, present inside kafka broker logs.

> root@a2md23297l:/tmp/kafka-logs-1# cat recovery-point-offset-checkpoint 
>   0
>   5
>   my-topic 0 0
>   kafkatopic_R2P1_1 0 0
>   my-topic 1 0
>   kafkatopic_R2P1 0 0
>   test 0 0
>   root@a2md23297l:/tmp/kafka-logs-1# cat replication-offset-checkpoint 
>   0
>   5
>   my-topic 0 0
>   kafkatopic_R2P1_1 0 2
>   my-topic 1 0
>   kafkatopic_R2P1 0 2
>   test 0 57

Fyi, **my-topic,kafkatopic_R2P1_1,my-topic,kafkatopic_R2P1,test** are the topics created.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK: `recovery-point-offset-checkpoint` is the internal broker log where Kafka tracks which messages (from-to offset) were successfully checkpointed to disk.

`replication-offset-checkpoint` is the internal broker log where Kafka tracks which messages (from-to offset) were successfully replicated to other brokers.

For more details you can take [a deeper look](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server) at: `kafka/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/LogOffsetMetadata.scala` and `ReplicaManager.scala`. The code is commented pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Marko is spot on.

the starting two numbers (0- Not sure what this is) (5-Number of partitions that are present on that  particular disk)

Numbers next to the topic name(0- Partition number of the topic)
next number is the offset which was flushed to the disk(recovery-point-offset-checpoint) and in replication-offset-checkpoint last offset which the replicas were successfully replicated the data